# Dynamically add data to different <div> tags in HTML file from a C++ code

Tags: javascript, html, c++, fstream, innerhtml

I have a HTML page which has 3 tabs (created using div tags).
From within my C++ code I need to keep pushing strings selectively to these 3 tabs.

**HTML File:**

```
<div id="tab1">
    <p>.S1</p>
    <p>S2</p>
........................
.....................
</div>

<div id="tab2">
    <p>S3.</p>
    <p>S4</p>
........................
.....................
</div>

<div id="tab3">
    <p>S5</p>
    <p>S6</p>
........................
.....................
</div>
```

**C++ code:**

```
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++) 
    {
       tabNum=Tab_num_generator();  // Generates the TAB number (HTML div)   
                               // to which this string should be pushed.
       std::string x= String_Genarator();
       PushToHTMLTab(tabNum, x);
       if(i==10)
       {
          SaveDataTOHTMLFile();
       }
    }
```

How do I implement `PushToHTMLTab()` & `SaveDataTOHTMLFile()` function.

I decided to have 3 `std::strings` which would hold the HTML tags & contents of these TABs, like:

```
std::string tab1-String = "<p>S1</p1>" + "<p>S2</p1>" +....
std::string tab2-String = "<p>S3</p1>" + "<p>S4</p1>" +....
std::string tab3-String = "<p>S5</p1>" + "<p>S6</p1>" +....
```

and then write these 3 strings into a snglr string like:

```
std::string FileString = tab1-String + tab2-String + tab3-String;

Finally write "FileString" to HTML file.
```

But this logic wouldn't work because, I'm saving data to file for
every 10 data extracted as evident in the logic above:

```
if(i==10)
{
   SaveDataTOHTMLFile();
}
```

So, how would I code `PushToHTMLTab()` & `SaveDataTOHTMLFile()` functions?

**OPTION 1:**

I could think of using 3 javascript functions (for each tab) where I
can keep on adding the new strings from C++ to these 3 javascript
functions & then make these javascript functions write the HTML
content using innerHTML.  Is this feaseable?

Comment: honestly, generating HTML with strings is a misstep IMO. There should be some kind of DOM/XML library you can use to build the document structure then save it to a file. If you do this then you should be able to insert into the DOM tree easily at any point.

Comment: have a look at libgdome: http://gdome2.cs.unibo.it/